# How to write a space delimited txt file in R?

Tags: r, file, text

I am very confused as I need to write a space delimited txt file, but columns have to be separated by space...

for example, this is my script to generate the space delimited file

```
write.table(main_analysis_covariate,"main_analysis_covariate.txt",
            col.names=T, quote=F,sep=" ")

head(main_analysis_covariate)
      FID     IID        V3      V4        V5         V6          V7        V8
1 1004951 1004951 -13.53970 3.63737 -2.615650  3.4962900 -0.27603800 -0.709574
2 1006785 1006785  -9.66567 2.49221 -0.391967 -0.0871995 -0.65907700 -0.181312
3 1007378 1007378 -12.97970 3.78742  1.228940 -0.9096680  0.83237900  1.973190
```

but I want a file looks like this

```
FID IID phenotype1 covariate1 covariate2
123456 123456 100 1 1
234567 234567 20 2 1
345678 345678 50 3 NA
```

Comment: The problem is a little unclear. Could you edit your post with the result of `x <- head(main_analysis_covariate); dput(x)` so we have a better understanding of your data?

Comment: What's the issue? It looks like this example file indeed has values separated by a single space. Do you instead want tab-delimited?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I edited my question, I want the file to look like the second one, but in my first table I got, it looked like tab delimited...

Comment: But `head(main_analysis_covariate)` doesn't show you the `.txt` file, it shows you the R dataframe. What does the `txt` file look like?

Comment: ah, I see,  I opened the txt file in linux, it was the right format.   I got confused that the data frame in R looks different. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DF` defined in the Note at the end try this (you will need to replace `stdout()` with your file name):

```
write.table(DF, stdout(), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
FID IID phenotype1 covariate1 covariate2
123456 123456 100 1 1
234567 234567 20 2 1
345678 345678 50 3 NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "FID IID phenotype1 covariate1 covariate2
123456 123456 100 1 1
234567 234567 20 2 1
345678 345678 50 3 NA"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines,  header = TRUE)
```